# Pass different type of value to single function as an arguments in Spark/Scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I am new in Scala. Can I Pass different type of values to single function as an argument in spark/scala.

I mean Generic function that can access Every type of value as an arguments(ex String,Int,Double etc.)

Ex.
Here bellow function will accept only Int value.

```
def Test(firstColumn : Int,secondColumn : Int) : (Int) = {
 //My Code here   
} 
val FLAG :Int =  Test(2,4)
```

Please suggest me something.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use type parameters and let Scala infer your return type and not specify a return type like this:

```
def Test[A,B](firstColumn : A,secondColumn : B) = {
     //My Code here   
    }
```

Comment: I don't want any specific return type. I will convert return value as per my need.

Comment: Just requirement is to pass any type of value to function.

Comment: Then you can use the second alternative. Scala will infer the return type automatically. A & B can be any types.